# Current location while in background using GeoLocator

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-background

I am using [GeoLocator package](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) (version 9.0.2). I am able to get the location as long as the app is in foreground with the permission set to "**While Using the App**". As soon as the app goes in the background the location stops working and I get the following error:

> LOCATION UPDATE FAILURE:Error reason: (null)Error description: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 1.)

I have enabled 'Location updates' in Background Modes Capability in Xcode. (https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/948)
[image]

When permission is set to '**Always**', I am able to get location as long as the phone's screen is on even when the app is in background. As soon as phone goes black/locked mode the location stops updating and have to open the app again for the process to start again.

What can I try next?

Comment: You need to take `Always Allow` permission in IOS.

Comment: An app is considered "in use" when you’re actively using it in the foreground, or when it is using location in the background, in which case a blue pill will display in your status bar. Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203033