# Flutter: Listen to location update while the is not in use even location permission is set to while using the app

Tags: flutter, google-maps, location, driver, tracking

I'm sorry if this question is duplicate but believe me there is no certain answer to the question `How to listen to current location changes while the app is minimized and location permission is set to while using the app` in flutter.

There is a same question but not given a solution
[Current location while in background using GeoLocator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75863824/current-location-while-in-background-using-geolocator)

I don't know how other big companies like `lyft` and `Uber` handled this problem?

I built a driver app which requires to share driver current location,it works perfectly when the app is in use (not minimized) but the moment user opens another app (my app goes to background) the location update stops.

I used to let drivers set their location permission to `always` and pushed to production, but drivers are not ok with letting their location accessed all the time.

The packages I used `location` and `permission_handler`.

there is part of my code where I listen to lcoation changes

```
 _listenLocationChanges(address, orderId) async {
    _locSubscription = location.onLocationChanged.listen((newLocationData) {
      print("listenning to location changes...........");
      print(newLocationData);
}
```

Of course I run `location.enableBackgroundMode(enable: true);` befor accessing the location and I added bellow permission to android manifist

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In modern phones the background tasks are killed by the OS for battery optimization. I don't think there is a possible way to track location when the app is not in use. For a continuous task running n background there are certain other tings that needs to be done visit https://dontkillmyapp.com/ for such remedies

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ubitech.sales&hl=en_IN&gl=US

This is the app that i made and did research for the same. I made foreground service for the purpose but the app use to get killed on many phones. Thats why I am stating this @zia

Comment: But how Uber and Lyft handling this problem, riders can track their driver wherease the location permission is set while using the app.

Comment: Well they have reputed developers they might have designed a native solution for tackling such problems. I have read about Facebook and WhatsApp and some other big companies. They use to have a contract with the manufacturer and their services are excluded from killing